# How to show data from two table order by average of second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL database with the following attributes.
services(id,name,details).
rating(id,sid,points).
In the rating table sid is foreign key of service table.
I want to show data in the following format
output(service id, name, details,average points) order by average points.
I have used the following query for this purpose

```
SELECT s.*, ROUND(COALESCE(AVG(r.points),0)) AS rating
FROM services s, rating r
WHERE s.id=r.sid
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Above query shows the result only when record exists in the rating table. I want to show the both records who's record exists or not in the rating table. if there is no record in the rating table than its average will be counted as zero.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the implicit join to a left outer join (which will return null) and wrap the avg in an ifnull

```
SELECT s.*, ifnull(ROUND(COALESCE(AVG(r.points),0)),0) AS rating
FROM services s
left outer join  rating r on s.id=r.sid
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for replying I have used the above query but it is showing only one record instead of all records of service table

Comment: Because you have an aggregation without a group by clause. Try changing s.* to s.id, s.name, s.details and add a group by clause on all these fields.

Comment: by adding group by clause my query is working fin. thanks a lot.